# combination of destinations in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have destinations array as `array('destination1', 'destination2', 'destination3', 'destination4')`. I want distinct combinations as

```
'destination1' => 'destination2'
'destination1' => 'destination3'
'destination1' => 'destination4'
'destination2' => 'destination3'
'destination2' => 'destination4'
```

what is the simple solution for doing this?

Comment: A simple two-loop approach, recursive approach... you name it, there are tons of way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to do like this

```
$arr = array('destination1', 'destination2', 'destination3', 'destination4');
$limit = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < ($limit - 2); $i++){
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $limit; $j++){
        echo $arr[$i].'=>'.$arr[$j].'</br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved and optimized version for any size:

```
while ($curr = array_shift($arr)) foreach ($arr as $item) echo $curr . '=>' . $item . '<br />';
```